# I am Not Able to run my Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I am not able to run my Maven Project as it show the error as "**Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.**" as shown in below diagram

My pom.xml file is :

[image]

and my web.xml file is

[image]

and my project structure is

[image: Project Structure and Tomcat error]

i did all the steps for maven projects from the refered site **http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/** and i got my maven build as success but not able to run a project as it shows error in console as

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
```

i tried , but still it coming as error..
Kindly help  me to rectify this
Thank You

Comment: Tomcat provides some logs to help you figure out whats wrong. My crystal ball is saying that 'servlet-api' should have the scope 'provided'

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to increase the Timeout of the Tomcat server, by default it times out after 45 seconds.

The Dependencies are taking time to load [more than 45 sec] and the server is timing out

Comment: look again at the dependencies, there are 2, one is test scope, and the second one is bogus, so I really doubt there is some timeout involved (and as a matter of fact I've never seen such deps loading timeout, never).

Comment: @RC .. i've given a scope for servlet-api as provided and its done.. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @user2715085 no problem ;)